# What requirements are there to vote in a Moderator Election on CV?

Tags: discussion, election

This came up in the Election chat room; what are the requirements that a user must meet in order to be eligible to *vote* in the moderator elections? There is a 300 rep barrier for nominations, but what restrictions, if any, beyond having a user account on CV are in place as regards the right to vote?

I couldn't find details specific to CV (or anything more general, but I didn't spend a long time looking across SE) on Meta.

Comment: I wrote this in the chat but, for those who don't read the chat, [here is a relevant Meta SO thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135778/why-is-150-reputation-needed-to-vote-in-elections) that says you need 150 rep. I haven't been able to find documentation of this anywhere but there.

Comment: Be careful! The requirements appear to vary among elections and among sites.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141099/eligibility-requirements-for-stack-overflow-moderator-elections for an example (which I am pretty sure does *not* apply to us).  For more on meta SO about this, here's a good search: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=election+requirements+minimum.

Comment: @whuber, given the heterogeneity you've pointed out across sites in the voting rules, what can we learn from that meta search? It's seeming like only an SE employee can answer this question.

Comment: @Macro I offered the link for anyone interested in learning more about elections on SE. Meta SO often includes information applicable across the board and not just to SO itself. I haven't found anything there that is sufficiently clear or recent to apply to our current election, but maybe a better or more persistent searcher will.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I consulted with mods on other SE sites and they showed me where the information is.  You can get to it by selecting the "Election" tab buried near the bottom of the first screen of our [election page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election).  After doing so, the contents of the box at the right will be updated to explain the voting requirements and procedure.  Here is a [direct link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=election).

Comment: +1. You couldn't have just told us you need 150 rep? You really wanted us to go to that link, I guess? ;)

Comment: @Macro [... teach a man to fish...](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day._Teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime).  Sorry about making you waste a click :-).

Comment: +1 Thanks - revelation dawns as this is how I'd seen details of the process in other SE site elections. I guess the colour scheme here (grey on grey) makes the tabs not stand out as much as on other sites (grey on white for example on [so]. Much appreciate you asking about this for us!

Comment: This information (that it requires 150 reputation) makes me wonder how many people have that much reputation. Oh, wait, I know how to find out... it's 1567 people. Of course, only a small fraction are active enough to even notice there's a vote. At typical response rates we might get 75 - 100 voters I guess.

Comment: @Glen_b The [elections page](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1761) has seen 232 visits, so I am hopeful we will see greater involvement than that.

Comment: @Glen_b As of right now, approximately 190 people have voted. ;-)

Comment: @whuber Thanks; actually I'd been watching the relevant badge, so I had a pretty good idea that the number was fairly close to that a couple of days ago. I am glad to be wrong.